# show all data of worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get user to open two files "UID map" and "Vl_lookup" and copy its content in a different filed named "SNS_Zone Stock Report - East"
one of the files may contain the filtered data or not but filter is applied to it

```
Sub copy_data()

Dim uid_map As String
MsgBox "Select UID Map workbook"
uid_map = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open uid_map
Workbooks("UID map.xlsx").Activate

Workbooks("UID Map.xlsx").Worksheets("Corrected prevail map").ShowAllData 'error:showalldata of worksheet  class failed 

Workbooks("UID map.xlsx").Worksheets("Corrected prevail map").Range("A:I").Copy _
Workbooks("SNS_Zone Stock Report - East.xlsm").Worksheets("Map").Range("A1") 'subscript out of range

Dim vlookup_formula As String
MsgBox "Select Vl_formula workbook"
vlookup_formula = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open vlookup_formula
Workbooks("Vl_formula.xlsx").Worksheets("Vl_formula").Range("A:I").Copy ( _
Workbooks("SNS_Zone Stock Report - East.xlsm").Worksheets("Vl_formula").Range("A1"))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Import Columns

- Not tested.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_data()
    
    ' Destination Workbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    ' If this is the workbook containing this code, then use...
    'Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    ' ... instead of:
    Set dwb = Workbooks("SNS_Zone Stock Report - East.xlsm")
    
    ' First Source Workbook
    MsgBox "Select UID Map workbook"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim uid_map As String: uid_map = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(uid_map)
    With swb.Worksheets("Corrected prevail map")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range("A:I").Copy dwb.Worksheets("Map").Range("A1")
    End With
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Second Source Workbook
    MsgBox "Select Vl_formula workbook"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim vlookup_formula As String
    vlookup_formula = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(vlookup_formula)
    With swb.Worksheets("Vl_formula")
        .Range("A:I").Copy dwb.Worksheets("Vl_formula").Range("A1")
    End With
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```